Up to date reference material for Group Policy Object: "Audit Object Access"
I have been investigating this policy for work, and have found this MS article. Two things concern me about it:

Despite the 2021 date, the event codes appear to be out-of-date. For example, this site offers translations from the older to the newer codes and vice versa.
The article mentions only that the objects must have a SACL defined. But is it not also the case that an audit policy must be defined on the object?

I am of course interested to know the answers to these two questions; however, my main query is; Where can I find an up-to-date, authoritative guide on how to use this policy?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I was careful to do so, or so I thought. The query, as described in the title, is to find a reliable, authoritative reference; the items in the list were given as reasons why the reference I have found does not seem reliable.
